# Vim in RStudio - how to call Ex Commands

Tags: vim, rstudio

I'm new to Vim and getting myself oriented to Vim in RStudio.  RStudio indicated that a quick reference card to the IDE of the key bindings can be called by switching to Vim mode and typing `:help`.  The available reference card also shows a variety of other `Ex Commands`.  I'm not having any luck calling up the `Ex C[enter link description here][1]ommands` but everything else is working just fine.

Obviously I am missing something simple ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded Vim emulation, alongside support for ex commands, was introduced with RStudio v0.99 (which, as of the time of this post, is not yet released, but is available as a [preview release](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)).

If you are running the preview release (or RStudio v0.99 or greater) and have Vim mode activated, you should be able to open the ex-command 'buffer' by typing `:` when an R source document has focus, and Vim mode is activated.

Comment: Thanks.  Simple fix ... I was using v0.98